# Spring Data JDBC aggregate ID in child objects

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

I was playing with Spring-Data-JDBC and encountered 2 issues. I have following entities with 1:N relationship.

```
------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product;

CREATE TABLE product (
    product_id int AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(250) not null,
    description varchar(512) not null
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product_line;

CREATE TABLE product_line (
    product_id int constraint fk_product_line_product references product(product_id),
    label varchar(250) not null
);

----------


@Data
@Builder
public class Product {

    @Id
    private Long productId;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @Singular
    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "product_id", keyColumn = "product_id")
    private Set<ProductLine> lines;
}

@Data
@Builder
public class ProductLine {

    private Long productId;

    private String label;

}
```

**Problem 1:** Following test case fails because I was expecting to have the `productId` populated in the `ProductLine` object but it is not. Is this the expected behavior of Spring Data JDBC?

```
@SpringBootTest
class SpringDataJdbcApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Test
    void saveTest() {

        Product product = Product.builder()
                .name("Product-1")
                .description("Description")
                .line(ProductLine
                        .builder()
                        .label("Line-label")
                        .build())
                .build();

        this.productRepository.save(product);

        assertThat(product.getProductId()).isNotNull();
        assertThat(product.getLines()).isNotNull().isNotEmpty().hasSize(1);
        assertThat(product.getLines().stream().findFirst()).isPresent();
        assertThat(product.getLines().stream().findFirst().get().getProductId()).isNotNull().isEqualTo(product.getProductId()); // -----> Fails here. 

    }

}
```

**Problem 2:** If I change `Set<ProductLine>` to `List<ProductLine>`, it fails due to `JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`, which means the product id set to 0 as seen in the log snippet below.

```
2022-09-10 22:33:12.393 DEBUG 18460 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT INTO "PRODUCT_LINE" ("LABEL", "PRODUCT_ID") VALUES (?, ?)]
2022-09-10 22:33:12.393 TRACE 18460 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils      : Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [Line-label], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type 12
2022-09-10 22:33:12.393 TRACE 18460 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils      : Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 2, parameter value [0], value class [java.lang.Integer], SQL type 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Following test case fails because I was expecting to have the productId populated in the ProductLine object but it is not. Is this the expected behavior of Spring Data JDBC?

Yes, if you want a `productId` you have to (and can easily) populate it yourself using plain Java code.
But you really shouldn't need the `productId` in the first place since if you follow Domain Driven Design, you will access a `ProductLine` exclusively from a `Product` which already has the id at hand.

The article https://spring.io/blog/2021/09/22/spring-data-jdbc-how-do-i-make-bidirectional-relationships might be helpful.

> If I change `Set<ProductLine>` to `List<ProductLine>`, it fails due to `JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`, which means the product id set to 0 as seen in the log snippet below.

You have two problems here:

1. You already have two sources for the `product_id` field: The relation from the aggregate root and the simple field, which may cause problems.
2. You mapped both the back reference to the aggregate root `idColumn` and the index of the list `keyColumn` to the same database column. Together with the simple field from above these are three values all mapped to the same column. Not good.
   The value that seems to win is the list index, resulting in the exception.
   In order to fix that, create an additional column in the `product_line` table and map the list index to it.

Comment: Thanks Jens! I realized the problem #1. And as you mentioned don’t need to have reference back in the model. However, with problem #2, it seems that for ordered collection the db needs to have index column. Is it something related to DDD patterns or SD JDBC specific implementation? I didn’t find any info in the docs.

Comment: Hi Rana, for a List you need a feed to store the index yes. Spring Data JDBC doesn't really have a special concept of "ordered collection".