# Primary key violation when inserting child entity

Tags: spring, collections, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

DB Schema (H2 database):

```sql
create table book (
    id_book bigint auto_increment not null primary key,
    title varchar(255) not null,
    id_author bigint not null,
    id_genre bigint not null
);

    
create table comment (
    id_comment bigint auto_increment not null primary key,
    id_book bigint not null,
    comment_text varchar(255) not null
);
```

Domain classes:

```java
public class Book {
    @Id
    @Column("id_book")
    private Long id;
    
    private String title;
    
    @Column("id_author")
    AggregateReference<Author, Long> author;
 
    @Column("id_genre")
    AggregateReference<Genre, Long> genre;
    
    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "id_book", keyColumn = "id_comment")
    List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public void addComment(String commentText) {
        comments.add(new Comment(commentText));
    }
       //getters and setters
}
```

````java
public class Comment {
    
    @Column("id_comment")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column("comment_text")
    private String text;
    
    public Comment(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    
    public Comment() {
    }
        //getters and setters
}

I have the problem when I add a comment to the book. 

```java
@Override
@Transactional
public String addComment(long bookId, String commentText) {
    var book = bookRepository.findById(bookId);
    return book.map(b -> {
        b.addComment(commentText);
        b = bookRepository.save(b);
        return bookConverter.convertToString(b);
    }).orElse("Book not found!");
}
````

It generates SQL like this...

```
    Executing SQL batch update [INSERT INTO "COMMENT" ("comment_text", "id_book", "id_comment") VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
```

... adds values for id_comment field like 0, 1, 2, 3 and these values intersect with existing ones. So I get Primary Key Violation. Why it adds `id_comment` field to the INSERT  expression?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73676462/spring-data-jdbc-aggregate-id-in-child-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why it adds id_comment field to the INSERT expression?

Because you told it to.

The following annotation tells Spring Data JDBC to store the index of the list in the `id_comment` column.

```java
@MappedCollection(idColumn = "id_book", keyColumn = "id_comment")
```

Your data model is missing a column for the list index. Add that column and use it as `keyColumn` in the `@MappedCollection` annotation